# How to show image after uploading from FileUploader into ImageControl

Tags: asp.net

I am using a FileUploader in webform to upload an image.What i want to do is as the image is browsed through FileUploader and selected, it should be displayed in the ImageControl as preview so that it can be further saved into DataBase.

Comment: If you plan on supporting only modern browsers, you can use the HTML 5 File API.

Comment: I am doing it in Asp.Net]

Comment: @ tomasmcguinness how to use that html5 api

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You will need to use some sort of Ajax, Jquery or flash control that
>   can access the file system and show a thumbnail of the selected file.
>   What you want is not possible otherwise, without uploading the file to
>   the server first.
>
> One more method is u can use external tools like [PicZard](http://piczard.com/demos/imageUpload/)  or [Rad
>   Controls for Asp.Net/Ajax](http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax/asyncupload.aspx) These Tools are very useful and will
>   meet your requirements.